# Enumerating and correlating tables to avoid cartesian joins

Tags: sql, window-functions, cartesian-product

I have a set of tables that I want to pull all the data from, with columns listing the contents of the ancillary tables.

For example:

**states**

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| AR | Arkansas |
| CT | Connecticut |
| MN | Maine |

**senators**

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| AR | Katie Britt |
| AR | Tommy Tuberville |
| CT | Chris Murphy |
| CT | Richard Blumenthal |
| MN | Angus King |
| MN | Susan Collins |

**representatives**

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| AR | Bruce Westerman |
| AR | French Hill |
| AR | Rick Crawford |
| AR | Steve Womack |
| CT | Jahana Hayes |
| CT | Jim Himes |
| CT | Joe Courtney |
| CT | John B. Larson |
| CT | Rosa DeLauro |
| MN | Chellie Pingree |
| MN | Jared Golden |

I want a column for the state, a column for the senators, and a column for the representatives like this:

| State | Senator | Representative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Arkansas | Katie Britt | Bruce Westerman |
| Arkansas | Tommy Tuberville | French Hill |
| Arkansas |  | Rick Crawford |
| Arkansas |  | Steve Womack |
| Connecticut | Chris Murphy | Jahana Hayes |
| Connecticut | Richard Blumenthal | Jim Himes |
| Connecticut |  | Joe Courtney |
| Connecticut |  | John B. Larson |
| Connecticut |  | Rosa DeLauro |
| Maine | Angus King | Chellie Pingree |
| Maine | Susan Collins | Jared Golden |

What I've come up with so far is this:

```sql
select states.name state, sens.name senator, reps.name representative
from states
left join
( select state_code, name
  , row_number() over (partition by state_code order by name) rn
  from representatives
) reps on reps.state_code = states.code 
full outer join 
( select state_code, name
  , row_number() over (partition by state_code order by name) rn
  from senators
) sens on sens.state_code = states.code and sens.rn = reps.rn
```

*(apologies, I earlier posted an incorrect version with the two joins the wrong way around)*

That works, but it relies on me joining to representatives first and then to senators, since there are always more reps. It breaks down if the representatives list is not populated for a state or if there are fewer rows populated than for senators.

My real world requirement is not states and senators and representatives, but this is an easy-to-explain analogy. The second and third tables are actually all in one table, and I need to do a dozen or more joins to it, not just two.

Any ideas how I can make this more general to handle the scenario where the second table in the from-join clause has fewer rows than the third, or zero?

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

Thanks to Chris Maurer for getting me further along the track. I am now trying to extend this to a third ancillary table.

**governors**

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| MN | Janet Mills |

```sql
select states.name as state, g.name as governor, s.name as senator, r.name as representative
from states
left join 
(
 (select g.*
  , row_number() over (partition by state_code order by name) as nbr
  from governors g) g
 full outer Join
 (Select s.*
  , row_number() over (partition by state_code order by name) as nbr
  from senators s) s
 on s.state_code=g.state_code and s.nbr=g.nbr
 full outer join
 (select r.*
  , row_number() over (partition by state_code order by name) as nbr
  from representatives r) r
 on r.state_code=coalesce(g.state_code,s.state_code) and r.nbr=coalesce(g.nbr,s.nbr)
) on states.code = coalesce(r.state_code,s.state_code,g.state_code)
```

| State | Governor | Senator | Representative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arkansas |  | Katie Britt | Bruce Westerman |
| Arkansas |  | Tommy Tuberville | French Hill |
| Arkansas |  |  | Rick Crawford |
| Arkansas |  |  | Steve Womack |
| Connecticut |  | Chris Murphy | Jahana Hayes |
| Connecticut |  | Richard Blumenthal | Jim Himes |
| Connecticut |  |  | Joe Courtney |
| Connecticut |  |  | John B. Larson |
| Connecticut |  |  | Rosa DeLauro |
| Maine | Janet Mills | Angus King | Chellie Pingree |
| Maine |  | Susan Collins | Jared Golden |

I think that works. I was going to ask something, but I fixed it by adding a coalesce to the `on` clause of the `r.state` join.

Comment: What are you doing is possible, but it's antithetical to the relational set theory underingpinning all databases, and therefore will not be as simple as you'd expect. In fact, typically this kind of thing is better handled in the client code or reporting tool.

Comment: Make liberal use of COALESCE with Full Outer Joins.  Every field has the potential to be null.

Comment: I accept your point, Joel, but SQL is also a reporting tool. I'm not going to be doing data processing on this result, it's purely for human consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.  Number your base tables first, full outer join them together second, and join in state name third.

```
Select st.name as state, s.name as senator, r.name as representative
From (
    (Select *
        , row_number() Over (Partition by code) as nbr
     From senators) s
  Full Outer Join
    (Select *
        , row_number() Over (Partition by code) as nbr
     From representatives) r
  On s.code=r.code and s.nbr=r.nbr
) Inner Join states st On Coalesce(r.code,s.code)=st.code
```

Comment: Right Join to states to make sure none are missed out?

Comment: Assumed states table is exhaustive, but if there is a state without senators OR representatives (!!!) then that would be better.

Comment: Hmmmm... I am rather surprised that the final join clause can access `r.code` and `s.code`, I would have thought that the `r` and `s` aliases would be hidden to it and it would just see two code columns and not be able to distinguish them. Clearly it can!

Comment: The parens DO enforce a sort of precedence.

Comment: The states list is exhaustive, but there might be a state with no data so I'm going from the state left joining to the result of the full outers.